# How do I test that something didn't invoke a background task?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous

I have a method that can be simplified to:

```
public static void InvokeBackground(Action action, CancellationToken cancellation)
{
    _ = Task.Run(() => action, cancellation);
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test that verifies `action` *isn't* invoked if `cancellation` token is already cancelled.

So a test might look like:

```
static CancellationToken CanceledToken { get; }

[Fact]
public async Task BackgroundInvoked_NotInvokedWhenCanceled()
{
    // verify token is indeed canceled
    Assert.True(CanceledToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    
    // set flag if invoked
    var invoked = false;
    InvokeBackground(() => invoked = true, CanceledToken);
    
    // delay to allow execution to proceed
    await Task.Delay(10);
    
    Assert.False(invoked);
}
```

But there's a couple issues:

- It's possible the wait time is not long enough, and this gets a false pass because it just hasn't happened *yet*
- Increasing the wait time makes it less likely to falsely pass, but technically never guarantees it
- Larger wait times leads to slow unit test runs (*one* may not make a difference, but many add up)

Is there a better way to test code like this, or a way to change the code to be more testable? Or does this end up being a situation where I just have to decide where on the "wait time vs test accuracy" curve I am ok with?

Comment: Maybe it's a side effect of how much you've reduced the problem, but it looks like this test is mostly just testing `Task.Run`'s implementation, and you shouldn't test other people's code.

Comment: I'd agree in general, but yeah, this is really a side-effect of the simplification, the actual code has more moving parts but they'd distract from the core problem.  That said, perhaps an answer is just to ensure there really is a logic-less method that calls to `Task.Run` (just like this) and keep the code that actually matters for testing isolated from that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to test code like this, or a way to change the code to be more testable?

One of the really nice results of unit testing is that it can expose weak designs.

> Or does this end up being a situation where I just have to decide where on the "wait time vs test accuracy" curve I am ok with?

Short answer: yes. There's no way to "negative test" fire-and-forget code like this. So you have to just choose a reasonable value. Which becomes less reasonable over time as more tests are added and the thread pool of the testing application becomes more saturated.

Long answer: your unit test is giving you valuable information about your application.

First, consider the semantics of the code and why it's difficult to unit test.

The unit test is difficult to write because it can't `await` some point at which the work is complete (or *not* complete, in this case). It's not possible for the unit test to know whether the work is supposed to be completed because the implementation is using fire-and-forget (in this case, the implementation just *is* fire-and-forget). One of the drawbacks of fire-and-forget is that the calling code *cannot know when it is completed*.

Next, consider how this affects the application: the application cannot know when it's fire-and-forget code is complete, so it *cannot know* when it is appropriate to shut down, because there may be some fire-and-forget code that isn't complete yet. Hence the general guideline: fire-and-forget is only appropriate for code that might not actually run.

The use case for such code is exceptionally small. I can say with confidence that at least 98% of all fire-and-forget code I've seen is flat-out wrong, because the developer *does* want the fire-and-forget code to run, and *not* running the code would result in semantic errors.

Unit tests are fantastic for gaining insight into your code, especially design deficiencies. Allow me to suggest that your unit test is *already* telling you something very useful: that `InvokeBackground` shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

> just have to decide where on the "wait time vs test accuracy" curve I am ok with?

I would say yes.

Let's take any finite timespan value you wait for in your test. So, there might be a bug in InvokeBackground, so that it waits longer(e.g. you timespan + 1) than the unit test, and only after that runs that action. In other words, whatever delay you put to the unit test, the function you test can run longer and finally run the action. So yes, some limits must exist.

For this particular case, I think it would be ok, if you define the InvokeBackground function, in such a way, that it throws OperationCancelledException if the token was cancelled.

I.e.

```cs
InvokeBackground(...)
{
  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  // ...
}
```

Then you know, that the function has exited, and you can check whether action was called or not.

P.S. And of course, it is possible to write InvokeBackground task, so that this check would pass, i.e.

```cs
InvokeBackground(Action action, CancellationToken token)
{
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async _ => 
  {
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    action();
  });
  token.ThrowIfCancellationReuested();
}
```

And if you, say, check whether a new thread was created, or check TaskScheduler, whether a new task was scheculed, we can rewrite this function so that it starts external process, etc.

So there should be a trade-off between how big percent of possible situtations can be covered by test and it's complexity.

I would say things like this are covered by code review.